# Clubs Transfer Strategies in FIFA 12

Tags: fifa-12

In career mode in FIFA 12, what factors determine a club's transfer strategy (e.g. whether they are a "buying" or "selling" club)?

I'm playing a career as a virtual pro but not playing as a manager. I'm playing for Liverpool, but in the course of 3 transfer windows they've sold off 6 or so star players (Suarez, Carroll, Reina, Johnson, Agger, Downing for those who are interested) without buying a single player. It's so completely unrealistic that it's really ruined the experience for me. I'm wondering if there are any factors that I have control over that I could change to make sure it doesn't happen again.

I realise I could just become the manager and then have (almost) complete control over transfers, but I would rather avoid all the minutia and just focus on playing.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult one to answer, it may be because the team is 4 and a half star and all teams which have offered money have been higher! (5star)
I played as Totenham and they actually bought suarez, which was good for me!
Another idea is to play as the team not just your player so (if your good) the players wont go out of form and wont be sold on!
To prevent everything your best bet is probably manager mode!